# Submit input value for checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I made a hide function for my radio button. It will show/hide a div whenever user clicked the radio button.
Javascript:

```
      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "CodeYes") {
                    $("#time").show();
                }
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "CodeNo") {
                    $("#time").hide();
                }
      });
```

HTML form:

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Code Initiated </label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
      <label class="radio radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="CodeInitiated" value="true" id="CodeYes"> Yes</label>
      <label class="radio radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="CodeInitiated" value="false" id="CodeNo"> No</label>
     </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group" id="time">
 <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Time </label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 ">
  <div Class="input-group ">
   <input Class="form-control input-sm" id="CodeInitiatedTime" name="CodeInitiatedTime" type="datetime-local" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

when the user click at `yes` button, time div will show up. the problem is, when the user click at `yes` button and type an input in the input box inside, then the user click at `no` button which means, he want to cancel out the previous input. when the form is submitted, the input still holding the value and bring it to the controller. how to make sure the value is only be sumbitted if radio button clicked at the correct button?

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Can you show us that code?

Answer (score 1):

When you are hiding the `div`, you can also `disable` the `input` (and vice-versa)

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "CodeYes") {
                $("#time").show();
                $("#time").find(":input").prop( "disabled", false ); //enable it back
            }
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "CodeNo") {
                $("#time").hide();
                $("#time").find(":input").prop( "disabled", true ); //disable on hide
            }
  });
```

Disabled inputs are not submitted.

Comment: @yusry How are you submitting the values?